# Issue while running command importPrivateKey in AWS Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS, and want to get DigitalSignature from AWS CloudHSM.
I am importing my private key using importPrivateKey command, but its not working.

Running Command:

```
importPrivateKey -f XXXXX.key -l XXXXX-imported -w 524299
```

Getting error:

```
BER encoded key length is 1218
Failed to get OBJ_ATTR_ENCRYPT attribute

        Cfm3WrapHostKey returned: 0x40000050

        LIQUIDSECURITY: No user is logged in to do this operation
```

Please Help if anyone have any idea...

Answer (score 0):

Here we are seeing the error like "No user is logged in to do this operation" so Try to login with CryptoUser (CU) and do the operation it will work.